# Ubercart XML feed for google shopping

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, google-shopping-api

I am currently trying to create a product feed from Ubercart for Google shopping through views. I cannot find a suitable answer with Google or the other stack overflow questions.

Has anyone done this before? 
How did you do it?
Did you need extra modules? if yes which ones?

**Modules used:**
Drupal 7
Ubercart 7.x-3.1
Views 7.x-3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this post:

[ubercart-and-google-merchant-integration](http://www.buentec.com/knowledge/ubercart-and-google-merchant-integration)

Comment: That is a really great solution. The question is not relevant for me anymore, but i marked it as answer for others.